# Different chapter verse numbering in Job 40 between Masoretic and other texts

Tags: hebrew-bible, job

Can someone explain how there came to be different chapter/verse numberings in Chapter 40 of the book of Job?  MT 40:25 becomes 41:1 in many other Bibles.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, thanks for contributing! Be sure to take our [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about us. [We're a little different from other sites.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/423)

Comment: This is often the case - English Bibles have slightly different verse and chapter divisions in many places.